# MySQL - Group By date/time functions on a large table

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of financial stock data in a MySQL table. The data is stored in a 1min tick per row format (OHLC). From that data I'd like to create 30min/hourly/daily aggregates. The problem that the table is enormous and grouping by date functions on the timestamp column yeilds horrible performance results.

Ex: The following query produces the right result but ends up taking too long.

```
SELECT market, max(timestamp) AS TS 
FROM tbl_data 
GROUP BY market, DATE(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
ORDER BY market, TS ASC
```

The table has a primary index on the (market, timestamp) columns. And I have also added an additional index on the timestamp column. However, that is not of much help as the usage of date/hour functions means a table scan regardless.

How can I improve the performance? Perhaps I should consider a different database than MySQL that provides specialized date/time indexes? if so what would be a good option?

One thing to note is that it would suffice if I could get the LAST row of each hour/day/timeframe. The database has tens of millions of rows.

MySQL version: 5.7

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit: Here is what Explain shows on a smaller DB of the exact same format:

[image]

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN [qeury]` say?

Comment: What is the MySQL version?

Comment: Sorry for not including that. I am running the same query here on a smaller DB just for the sake of testing but the results are the same: https://i.imgur.com/kZUx3k8.png   MYSQL version: 5.7

Comment: The qeury is using a full covering index scan. you can see by type index and using index in the extra column. Using temporary; using filesort makes it slow  MySQL is going to create a temporary MyISAM memory table to hold the results. if the temporary MyISAM memory table become to big it will be coverted into a temporary disk based MyISAM. filesort is really a wrong name it is really a quicksort algorithm that will run on the temporary memory table or on the temporary disk table for results sorting. Do you really need the orderd results? if not you can disable the ORDER BY with `ORDER BY NULL`

Comment: If the existing table data never change (no updates, no deletions, just inserts), the solution to your problem is a separate table that contains the desired aggregate values. A cron job in the backend computes the aggregate values every 15 minutes (more or less, depending on how fresh you need to have the aggregate data); the frontend reads from the aggregate table. The backend job doesn't have to read huge amounts of data, it processes only what was added since its last execution; the frontend queries are simple and fast, they don't have to compute anything.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the replies. And unfortunately, I tried that before and it didn't impact the performance whatsoever. It seems to be the case that the vast majority of time is consumed by mysql to loop through each row and extract the HOUR() from the timestamp field and group on the extracted value. Which makes sense. The ORDER seems to be applied after all of the grouping is done which is rather trivial.

Comment: @axiac Thanks for the reply. That was actually my last resort. Considering how many different aggregations I'm interested in doing, the number of tables and data points is going to grow significantly. That's why I wanted to generate the data at runtime rather than creating a separate table with said aggregate values. Do you happen to know in case that's possible at all to do with MySQL?

Comment: send 1 bitcoin to me from bittrex : )

Comment: Maybe you ought to break timestamp into separate fields upon insertion.  That way you won't need to call the `DATE()` and `HOUR()` functions for each and every row during `SELECT`.  This should speed things up a bit, but only an experiment can tell you how much exactly.

Comment: As you already mentioned in the question, passing `timestamp` to a function renders the index useless. It is used, however, by the `WHERE` clause, if you put one in your query to limit the data used to compute the result set. I guess you never need to compute aggregate values for all the data since the beginning of time.

Comment: @tonypdmtr I guess that's something I can try. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @axiac I am already doing that but because the data is in 1 min format, if you want to get the last x days worth of data... that becomes a bitch regardless :/ I guess I'll try doing it the way you mentioned first and see how that plays out data-size wise!

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did not know that those columns could be indexed. Thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: The change suggested by @tonypdmtr should also make a big improvement on the query speed. Create a multicolumn index on *(market, date, hour)* (specifically in this order). Anyway, if you want to improve the speed you have to spend some storage space.

Comment: @axiac actually, I am merging all 3 suggestions you guys gave me. I am going to try to add a few virtual columns that compute date, hour and add the index the way you mentioned. That should actually fix it (at least theoretically). Thanks for the help! Much appreciated.

Comment: and the unanswered question was: would you be better off with another dbms? an answer to which is always going to be opinion based. But I suggest you would benefit from  a partitioned table (probably by month)  and window functions that will give you back the "last row" for each hour efficiently. MariaDB & Postgres provide both partitioning and window functions. MySQL lacks window functions until v8 is production ready. MariaDB may be easier for you to transition to.